# How to call specific php function through jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax call to a php file. However, the file contains multiple defined functions, all somewhat similar.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


function loadall(){
    $querystring = "SELECT location, filetype, author FROM globalposts ORDER 
BY date DESC";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $querystring);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($row);
}

function jasperbriggsload(){
    $querystring = "SELECT title, location FROM omar ORDER BY date DESC";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $querystring);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

I have not done overloaded methods with variables, though they might work with my db structure.

My main question is how to call a specific function in an external php through ajax. if I wanted to call
    loadall()
or
    jasperbriggsload()
through just ajax arguments

Comment: What do you mean?  Your ajax can pass in a get or post parameter that your php can check for, and decide on which method to call based on that parameter.

Comment: What you're describing is the functionality provided by some frameworks - if you want to implement it in vanilla php you'll need to inspect the GET or POST data at the start of the PHP script and direct the execution flow accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) passing the function name sent by ajax as argument. Like this:

```
<?php
function test(){
    //your code
}

//This will run the test() function
call_user_func('test');

//This will run the function named as the content of $_REQUEST['funcName']
call_user_func($_REQUEST['funcName']);
?>
```